# Magento continue shopping url change

Tags: magento

Is there any setting in magento backend to change continue shopping url ? If there any settings is there let me know How I can change. I am using Magento 1.7.x

Comment: Continue shopping after what? Checkout?

Comment: yes on cart page and checkout page its using continue shopping url. Such as $this->getContinueShoppingUrl()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly not, I've always wondered why this hasn't been in the configuration.  You have two choices, you can either extend `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` to apply logic to determine what URL to use or you can set the the URL in the template.

```
<?php $this->setContinueShoppingUrl('http://URL.com'); ?>

<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart is Empty') ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="cart-empty">
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s">here</a> to continue shopping.', $this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?></p>
</div>
```

However, if you're going to set it in the template, you might as well just remove change `<?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s">here</a> to continue shopping.', $this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>` to `<?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="http://URL.COM">here</a> to continue shopping.') ?>`

Comment: Having said that, it wouldn't be too difficult to add that field into the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

To change redirect url of continue shopping button in "NOT" empty shopping cart just add the second code line following highlighted with asterix ** in ...your_theme/default/checkout/cart.phtml:

```
<?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
**<?php $this->setContinueShoppingUrl('http://yoursite.com/...'); ?>**
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

cheap & effective

Thanks to previous answer/hint